# The result is different in R if some calculation is wrapping with function

Tags: r

I am trying to optimized my R code, and the below was the code I used with functions:

```
set.seed(1)
C.set <- seq(.601,.999,.002) 

Find_N <- function(n,mu0,delta.mu.H0,cv0,cv1,cv2,n.sim) {
  cutoff <- 0.025
  CC <- rep(0,n)
  expected.n <- rep(0,n)
  for (n1 in 11:(n-11)) {
    
    CC[n1] <- get.C(n1,mu0=mu0,mu1=mu0-delta.mu.H0,cv0=cv0,cv1=cv1,alpha.fcr=cutoff,n.sim=n.sim)

    get.En <- get.En(n1,n=n,mu0=mu0,mu1=mu0,cv0=cv0,cv1=cv1,n.sim=n.sim,CC[n1])
    expected.n[n1] <- get.En$E.n 
  }
  optimal.N <- seq(11,n1)[which.min(expected.n[11:n1])]
  return(list(optimal.N))  
}

#### the functions inside the Find_N #####
get.C <- function(n1,mu0,mu1,cv0,cv1,alpha.fcr,n.sim) {
  prob.within <- get.prob.within(n1,mu0,mu1,cv0,cv1,n.sim)
  ind.optimal.C <- binary_search(prob.within,alpha.fcr)
  optimal.C <- C.set[ind.optimal.C]
  return(optimal.C)
}


get.En <- function(n1,n,mu0,mu1,cv0,cv1,n.sim,C) {
  prob.within <- get.prob.within(n1,mu0,mu1,cv0,cv1,n.sim)
  alpha <- mean(prob.within>C)  
  E.n <- n1*alpha+(1-alpha)*n
  list(E.n=E.n,alpha=alpha)
}

#############################
```

Now I'm trying to break up the function, that I want to used them directly inside their `Find_N` function:

```
Find_N <- function(n,mu0,delta.mu.H0,cv0,cv1,cv2,n.sim) {
  alpha.fcr <- 0.025
  CC <- rep(0,n)
  expected.n <- rep(0,n)
  increase <- rep(0,n)
  for (n1 in 11:(n-11)) {
    print(n1)
    
    ###### this is the direct for get.C ###########
    prob.within <- get.prob.within(n1,mu0,mu1,cv0,cv1,n.sim)
    ind.optimal.C <- binary_search(prob.within,alpha.fcr)
    optimal.C <- C.set[ind.optimal.C]
    CC1[n1] <- optimal.C
     
    ###### this is the direct for get.En ###########
    prob.within <- get.prob.within(n1,mu0,mu1,cv0,cv1,n.sim)
    C <- CC[n1]
    alpha <- mean(prob.within>C)
    expected.n1[n1] <- n1*alpha+(1-alpha)*n 
    
  }
  optimal.N <- seq(11,n1)[which.min(expected.n[11:n1])]
  return(list(optimal.N))   

}
```

however, these two `Find_N` calculates different results, Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Not sure if you'll get a lot of bites on this, but you will need to show how you intend to call these functions and with what sample data.

Comment: Packages for all those undefined functions?

Comment: How are you defining mu1 in your new function

Answer (score 2):

This could be because you have a typo. In your first code, you pass `mu0=mu0,mu1=mu0` to `get.En()`, which means `get.prob.within()` receives `n1,mu0,mu0` as its first three arguments, but in the second code you directly supply `get.prob.within()` with `n1,mu0,mu1` as the first three arguments.